# eclipse not using/finding build path sources?

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I have added the 'Forge' folder as a source folder, and stuck it in the build path, all to no effect. I have tried using the quickfix solution "fix project setup" giving me the error in the box; in fact, 78, 370 errors. Yes, you read that right. 78,370 errors. I have tried both reinstalling the forge (required source) directory and reinstalling eclipse, all to no avail.

My eclipse page screenshot: [had to crop and move around my package explorerto meet the 2 MB limit] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCDA7.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to add that additional project as a reference in your main project in its build path.

Answer (score 0):

Is the project that contains the cpw package a different Java project? Then in your project add the project as follows. Go to - Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add. Here look for the other project and add it.